# Apply CSS to all select2 but not to id contains a letter and vice versa

Tags: css, jquery-select2

I want to write CSS for all select2 boxes that the ids not contains `month` and I did the flow.

```
span[id *= "month"]{
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

This works fine for containing the letter.

**But the following should work for not, but it works for all which id contains `month` as well.**

```
span:not([id *= "month"]){
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

**Note:** why I am using `span` tag, cause `select` generates the span tag with select tag id like below:

```
<span title="Month" id="select2-ga_regsmonth-container" class="select2-selection__rendered">Month</span>
```

What did I wrong?
Appreciate

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine. Maybe you can post your HTML?

```css
span:not([id *="month"]) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<span id="year">Year</span>
<span id="month">Month</span>
```

Comment: Select2 generates that automatically